# '>' not supported between instances of 'QuerySet' and 'int' in Django

Tags: python, django

this is my code:

```
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  before_requests = MyModel.objects.filter(expired_at__lte=now)
  if before_requests  < 0:
     # some code
```

and i have this error:

```
DateTimeField MyModel.expired_at received a naive datetime (2021-06-22 11:34:44.810749) while time zone support is active.
  warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"
'>' not supported between instances of 'QuerySet' and 'int'
```

can every one help me?

Comment: I doubt that is the code that is causing this error.. What are you doing with `before_requests` once you have it?

Comment: @michjnich , i need list of expired records.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: Yes, but what are you doing with that. You haven't given enough info here to help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyModel.objects.filter(expired_at__lte=now)
```

this returns a QuerySet which is basically a list - it can be empty, or contain one or multiple instances.
If you are certain that you only want the first if there is any, change it to:

```
first_before_request = MyModel.objects.filter(expired_at__lte=now).first()
if first_before_request:
    # compare it to the int value
```

You have not included in your question the actual code that does the comparison and is causing the error, so this is a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.utils import timezone

before_requests = MyModel.objects.filter(expired_at__lte=timezone.now())
```

Comment: i have this error by your code:  '>' not supported between instances of 'QuerySet' and 'int'

Comment: This isn't answering the original question - it's addressing the warning, not the error.

Comment: @michjnich, thanks, i found problem! your query in true!